# Are there bonus spells for prime ability scores?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ability-scores

In previous versions, spell casters were given bonuses to available spells based on their casting ability score. I don't remember exact stats but to make an example, A wizard would be able to memorize extra spells:

Int 14 = 1 extra lvl 1
Int 15 = 2 extra LVL 1
Int 16 = 2 extra lvl 1 and 1 extra lvl 2
Int 17 = 2 extra lvl 1, 2 extra lvl 2 and is required for casting lvl 8 spells
Int 18 = 2 extra lvl 1, 2 extra lvl 2, 1 extra lvl 3, and is required for casting lvl 9 spells.

I can't seem to find mention of this bonus in D&D 5th Edition. Does it apply to prepared spell limit, spell slots, or has it been obsoleted?

Note: I also can't seem to find mention of a prepared spell limit, or feats.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## There is no such bonus for spells known

Wizards learn their spell on level up or through transcribing them into a spellbook, but their ability score does not have an effect on how many they can learn or do learn on level up.

For classes that only get spells through level up or are prepared casters, the number of spells known can be found in the table for those classes in the Player's Handbook. The number that can be prepare can be found in the class descriptions usually in a section called "Preparing and Casting Spells". Preparing spells *does* actually usually depend on the spellcasting stat.

For example for cleric it says:

> You prepare the list of cleric spells that are available for you to cast, choosing from the cleric spell list. When you do so, choose a number of cleric spells equal to your Wisdom modifier + your cleric level (minimum of one spell).

Answer (score 10):

**The bonus is for spells Prepared, for casters that Prepare their spells**
Cleric, Druid, Paladin & Wizard that I can think of. (Thanks Phil)

> You prepare the list of druid spells that are available for you to cast, choosing from the druid spell list. When you do so, choose a number of druid spells equal to your Wisdom modifier + your druid level (minimum of one spell). The spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots. 
>   *PHB **Druid** p66*

They know all their spells of the relevant level, however, can only prepare an amount as above each day.

Wizards can add spells to their spellbook (as described in the PHB). They don't have a limit on the number of spells they can *"know"* but they do have a limit on the spells they can have *"prepared"* as above.

Other casters like Sorcerer, Bard and Warlock have a column in their class table defining how many spells they know at each level.

Comment: Wizards have a limit to spells prepared, that works the same way as for the divine casters.

Comment: yes I found it, Wizard have no limit to what can be in their book, but prepared is limited in same manner except with INT bonus not wisdom bonus.

Answer (score 4):

This has varied over the editions.  In AD&D 1e, clerics and druids got this sort of bonus, and magic users and illusionists did not.

In 5e, your spell slots are fixed by your level and class.  Where your casting ability score comes into play is that for Clerics, Druids, Paladins, and Wizards, the number of your spells you can have prepared goes up if you have a higher prime ability.  Each of those is detailed in a paragraph of the Players Handbook for each class.  Bards, Eldritch Knights, Arcane Tricksters, Sorcerers, and Warlocks don't even get that benefit; their prime ability only affects their Spell Attack Bonus and Spell Save DC.

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring specifically altered the Spells per day given based on your Ability score. As far as I know this was taken out after 3.5 and was not added in 5th edition.

Comment: [Have you read how it works in 5th](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PlayerBasicRulesV03.pdf=page#30)?   For spells prepared "...choose a number of wizard spells
from your spellbook equal to your Intelligence modifier + your wizard level (minimum of one spell). The spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots." If you are referring to *Spell Slots*, please make that clear in your answer.  Thanks for joining us at RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how a Q&A site is different from a forum.  "As far as I know" is not good support for an answer.